# Getting peak load for Azure MySQL service from Azure Log Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I am trying to find peak CPU usage and peak memory usage for Azure MySQL service using Log Analytics. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Was trying to add this using a kusto query to my dashboard. I was able to figure this out. Posted answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out and have added this in my dashboard using the Azure Metrics component and customizing the presentation to table view instead of graph view. I don't have visibility to the actual query that generates this data but I am able to access the data in text/table form.